# Suma de cadena de caracteres incluyendo espacios Javascript

Tags: javascript

Compañeros, una ayuda actualmente realizo una funcion en Javascript que me permita realizar la suma de caracteres pero debe incluir espacios vacios. la situacion es que la funcion realiza la suma pero en el momento de un espacio vacios no sabria que hacer para que busque el espacio vacio o lo remplace por un 0 o se retire del array. Si alguien me puede ayudar o guia para saber que podria hacer se lo agradeceria.

```
var numero = prompt("introduzca un número");
console.log("Variable numero:" +numero);

if (numero >= 10) {
    var res = numero.split("");
    console.log("Metodo split" + res);

    // Cantidad de caracteres para saber la interacion en el for
    var arrayLength = res.length;
    console.log("Cantidad de caracteres:   " + arrayLength);
    numero = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        a = Number(res[i]);
        console.log(a);
        numero = numero + a;
        console.log(typeof numero);
        console.log("suma:   " + numero);
    }
    alert(numero);
} else {
  alert(numero);
  console.log("false en if    " + numero);
}
```

Comment: Sería muy útil si incluyes un ejemplo de cadena de entrada y cual es la salida esperada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto debería funcionar como le necesitas, de esta forma no necesitas reemplazar nada:

```js
var numero = prompt("introduzca un número");
var numerosn = "";
/*aquí se recorre cada carácter de la cadeana y se identifican los espacios en blanco para que no sean tomados*/
for(a = 0; a < numero.length; a++){ 
  if(numero[a] != " "){
  numerosn = numerosn + numero[a];
  }
}
/*----*/
console.log("Variable numero:" +numerosn);

if (numerosn >= 10) {
    var res = numerosn.split("");
    console.log("Metodo split" + res);

    // Cantidad de caracteres para saber la interacion en el for
    var arrayLength = res.length;
    console.log("Cantidad de caracteres:   " + arrayLength);
    numerosn = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        a = Number(res[i]);
        console.log(a);
        numerosn = numerosn + a;
        console.log(typeof numerosn);
        console.log("suma:   " + numerosn);
    }
    alert(numerosn);
} else {
  alert(numerosn);
  console.log("false en if    " + numerosn);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes convertir los espacios en un 1 para que lo agregue en la suma final, comparando si 
res[i] = 0, se convierta en 1

```
var numero = prompt("introduzca un número");
console.log("Variable numero:" +numero);

if (numero >= 10) {
    var res = numero.split("");
    console.log("Metodo split" + res);

    // Cantidad de caracteres para saber la interacion en el for
    var arrayLength = res.length;
    console.log("Cantidad de caracteres:   " + arrayLength);
    numero = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        a = Number(res[i])==0?1:Number(res[i]);        
        numero = numero + a;
        console.log(typeof numero);
        console.log("suma:   " + numero);
    }
    alert(numero);
} else {
  alert(numero);
  console.log("false en if    " + numero);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

La idea que tienes originalmente de reemplazar los espacios en blanco por 0 es perfectamente valida, para hacer eso puedes usar el metodo `replace()` que lo que hace es buscar en una cadena un valor especifico y lo reemplaza por otro. Si quieres mas informacion puedes ver como funciona [aqui](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)

Finalmente tu codigo quedaria asi, nota que hago el replace justo despues de recivir la variable del prompt():

```js
var numero = prompt("introduzca un número"); 
console.log("Variable numero:" +numero); 
//Aqui reemplazamos los espacios por 0
numero = numero.replace(" ", "0");
console.log("Variable sin espacio:" +numero);
if (numero >= 10) { 
    console.log("Variable numero:" +numero); 
    var res = numero.split(""); 
    console.log("Metodo split" + res);

    // Cantidad de caracteres para saber la interacion en el for
    var arrayLength = res.length;
    console.log("Cantidad de caracteres:   " + arrayLength);
    numero = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        a = Number(res[i]);
        console.log(a);
        numero = numero + a;
        console.log(typeof numero);
        console.log("suma:   " + numero);
    }
    
    alert(numero);
} else { 
    alert(numero); 
    console.log("false en if " + numero); 
}
```